# How to save the code object in file?

Tags: python

How to save the code object (_ _ code _ _) in file?

```
>>> c
<code object foo at 0x022E7660, file "<console>", line 1>
>>> pickle.dump(c, f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'code'>: attribute lookup builtins.code failed
>>> f.write(c)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'code' does not support the buffer interface
```

Comment: Code objects are inherently platform-dependent, and `pickle` is a platform-independent format.  There is no easy way to represent a code object platform-independently, but usually you don't need to.  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 10):

Not sure what you are trying to do but you can use the [marshal](http://docs.python.org/library/marshal.html) module for this:

```
>>> import marshal
>>> def f():
...    print 'f'
>>> marshal.dump(f.__code__, open('test.dump'))
>>> code = marshal.load(open('test.dump'))
>>> f.__code__ == code
True
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(code)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('f')
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```